# Getting music from a dead iPod Touch

Tags: ipod-touch, battery

I have a 3rd generation iPod touch with a dead battery and want to get the music off of it for my new one.

It powers up fine with the AC power cord but nothing with the PC's USB.

Any short fix besides sending it out for a new battery?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your touch is consuming more power then your USB port can deliver at run-time.  See if you can find a PC that can supply enough current to get it to boot on a PC and use one of those non-apple sanctified recovery software.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like I am perpetuating a myth, but here goes:

Laptops USB drives supposedly give out less power than workstation USB drives. Try using the USB port on a workstation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the USB cable?  Try it with your friends USB cable and see if that works.

Shouldn't your music be in iTunes anyway?

Comment: "Shouldn't your music be in iTunes anyway?" Only music that was purchased from there would be. I have a lot of my CD collection on my iPod, which is probably about 30GB worth, and that's not on iTunes.

Comment: How did you get it on your iPod without it being in iTunes?